# Listar registros do MySQL ordenados alfabeticamente no PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Criei uma tabela para armazenar registros de nomes de pessoas onde o campo `a_tipo` armazenará a letra do alfabeto relacionada ao nome, a estrutura da tabela está assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Com o PHP fiz a conexão com o banco de dados e exibo a lista de registros:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `a_cadastro` ORDER BY `a_tipo` ASC;";
```

Ordenei pelo alfabeto, que foi armazenado no campo `a_tipo` de modo ascendente, e a listagem está ok.

A dificuldade que estou enfrentando é que, a cada lista de nomes que começam com a letra A, preciso criar um glossário, que seria exibido assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não estou conseguindo organizar a lógica para listar desse modo, que no HTML ficaria:

```
<h1>Lista de nomes</h1>

<h2>A</h2>

<ul>
  <li>Abilio</li>
  <li>Acácio</li>
  <li>Ademilson</li>
  <li>Afonso</li>
</ul>

<h2>B</h2>

<ul>
  <li>Benedita</li>
  <li>Bernardo</li>
  <li>Bianca</li>
  <li>Beatriz</li>
</ul>
```

[.... Todas as letras, se houver nomes nos registros ....]

Alguém pode ajudar, não é má vontade, mas não sei por onde começar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segue um script rápido que eu fiz, não consegui testar, mas acredito que funcione. No `foreach` você percorre os dados do banco você pode mudar para `while` caso esteja implementando de tal forma.

```
<?php
echo '<h1>Lista de nomes</h1>';
$utimaLetra = '';
foreach($dados as $dado) {

    if(strtoupper($utimaLetra) != strtoupper(substr($dado['a_tipo'], 0, 1))) {
         if($utimaLetra != '') {
             echo '</ul>';
         }
         echo '<h2>'.strtoupper(substr($dado['a_tipo'], 0, 1)).'</h2>';
         echo '<ul>';
         $utimaLetra = strtoupper(substr($dado['a_tipo'], 0, 1));
    }

    echo '<li>'.$dado['a_tipo'].'</li>';
}

echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: entendi a lógica e apliquei, obrigado pelo seu tempo!